# C# removing a control from a parent container and List

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, user-controls

I have 2 controls that inherit `UserControl`
one is a container and the other is a collection of basic text boxes lables etc. hereby labeled as `ContainerControl` and `ComboControl`.

`ContainerControl` contains a `List<ComboControl>` and a foreach loop that adds them to a `FlowLayoutPanel`. `ComboControl` has a button that I would like to be used to clear itself from its parent's List.

I am not sure what the best way of doing this would be. `this.parent` and cast to `ContainerControl` or would `Dispose()` work? I'm fairly sure I could pass a ref to the `List`, but that sounds needlessly messy...

```
 public partial class ContainerControl : UserControl
 {
    List<ComboControl> ComboControls = new List<ComboControl>();
    ...
    //procederaly generate and fill ComboControls here
    ...
    foreach (ComboControl value in ComboControls)
    {
        this.flowLayoutTable.Controls.Add(value);
    }
 ...
 }

 public partial class ComboControl : UserControl
 {
     private void BtnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //what goes here
    }
 ...
 }
```

Comment: You have to post some code so that someone can help you.

Comment: ok placed some mockup code.

Comment: `this.flowLayoutTable.Controls.Clear()` and `ComboControls.Clear()` should be enough. However, if there are other references to the combo controls (such as events register to them) you will need to clean that up as well, otherwise you might get a memory leak.

Comment: ok cool will that  wouldent clear them from the list as well would it?

Answer (score 2):

Along the lines of what  [Zohar Peled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3094533/zohar-peled) said, something like this to remove a control to avoid leaking resources.

```
private void cleanup(Control c)
{          
    foreach(Control child in c.Controls)        
        cleanup(child);         

    if (c.Parent != null)
    {
        c.Parent.Controls.Remove(c);
        c.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For scenario like this i would use a custom event to send a delete request to parent control :

your ComboControl with Custom Event :

```
 //Create Custom Event
    public delegate void DeleteControlDelegate(object sender);

    public partial class ComboControl : UserControl
    {
        //Custom Event to send Delete request
        public event DeleteControlDelegate DeleteControlDelegate;

        public ComboControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Invoke Custom Event
        private void OnDeleteControl(object sender)
        {
            DeleteControlDelegate?.Invoke(sender);
        }

        private void BtnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //On ButtonClick send Delete request
           OnDeleteControl(this);
        }
    }
```

and in your ContainerControl subscribe to event of each ComboControl :

```
List<ComboControl> _comboControls = new List<ComboControl>();

        public ContainerControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ContainerControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _comboControls.Add(new ComboControl());
            _comboControls.Add(new ComboControl());
            _comboControls.Add(new ComboControl());

            foreach (ComboControl value in _comboControls)
            {
                flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(value);
                //Subscribe to Custom Event here
                value.DeleteControlDelegate += Value_DeleteControlDelegate;
            }
        }

        private void Value_DeleteControlDelegate(object sender)
        {
            //When Raised Delete ComboControl
            flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove((Control) sender);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Im loving this method however im getting a DeleteControlDelegate is a type but used as a value on both these lines

    value.DeleteControlDelegate += Value_DeleteControlDelegate;

    DeleteControlDelegate?.Invoke(sender);

will poke at till i figure it out. (havent really looked in to Deligates yet)

Comment: I did but i had to replace:

public delegate void DeleteControlDelegate(object sender);

With:

public event EventHandler DeleteControlDelegate(object sender);
And I think a few other minor changes